# How can I add points to a numpy array more efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, optimization

I'm fairly new to python, so I don't know all the tips and tricks quite yet.  But I'm trying to read in data line by line from a file, then into a numpy array.  I have to read it in line by line in this manner, but I have freedom when it comes to moving that data into the array.  Here is the relevant code:

```
xyzi_point_array = np.zeros((0,4))
x_list = []
y_list = []
z_list = []
i_list = []
points_read = 0
while True:     #FOR EVERY LINE DO:
    line = decryptLine(inFile.readline())   #grabs the next line of data
    if not line: break

    .
    .
    .

    index = 0
    for entry in line:      #FOR EVERY VALUE IN THE LINE
        x_list.append(X)
        y_list.append(Y)
        z_list.append(z_catalog[index])
        i_list.append(entry)
        index += 1
        points_read += 1

xyzi_point_array = np.zeros((points_read,4))
xyzi_point_array[:,0] = x_list
xyzi_point_array[:,1] = y_list
xyzi_point_array[:,2] = z_list
xyzi_point_array[:,3] = i_list
```

Where `X` and `Y` are scalars which are different for each line, and where `z_catalog` is a 1D numpy array.

For smaller data sets, the imbedded for loop is the biggest draw, with the `xyzi_point_array[points_read,:] =` line taking the majority of processor time.  However with larger data sets, working with `tempArr` to expand `xyzi_point_array` becomes the worst, so I'll need to optimize both.

Any ideas?  General tips on how to better handle numpy arrays are also welcome, I come from a C++ background, and am probably not handling these arrays in the most pythonic way..

For reference, here is the lineprofiler readout for this bit of the code:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   138       150          233      1.6      0.0          index = 0
   139    489600       468293      1.0     11.6          for entry in line:      #FOR EVERY VALUE IN THE LINE
   140    489450       457227      0.9     11.4              x_list.append(lineX)
   141    489450       441687      0.9     11.0              y_list.append(lineY)
   142    489450       541891      1.1     13.5              z_list.append(z_catalog[index])
   143    489450       450191      0.9     11.2              i_list.append(entry)
   144    489450       421573      0.9     10.5              index += 1 
   145    489450       408764      0.8     10.2              points_read += 1
   146                                            
   149         1           78     78.0      0.0      xyzi_point_array = np.zeros((points_read,4))
   150         1        39539  39539.0      1.0      xyzi_point_array[:,0] = x_list
   151         1        33876  33876.0      0.8      xyzi_point_array[:,1] = y_list
   152         1        48619  48619.0      1.2      xyzi_point_array[:,2] = z_list
   153         1        47219  47219.0      1.2      xyzi_point_array[:,3] = i_list
```

Comment: That's ugly. Without exactly looking for "what is going on"... The idea of using arrays for adding points AND rewriting the array every time in a loop is very bad. Can't you fill some list-based data-structure (somewhing which is more performant for append) and convert this to a numpy array at the end (when dimensions are known and only one array-creation step is enough)? It seems, that "data-point" 0 will be rewritten n-1 (number of data-points) times (for every successor, the array will be "extended" = copied + some new stuff). Of course that's slow!

Comment: @sascha Alright, I'll post the new code using this, it dropped run time by 20%

Comment: I think there should me much much more speedup possible. In theory we are comparing two methods, where one method is doing quadratically more work than the other (copy-operations; hard to explain). I'm curious about your changes. Could you add your second approach? EDIT: you added it :-)

Comment: Your code is really hard to read, because there is no example of your file/lines. And did you mix the two approaches now (is the last indentation correct?)? Well, but still: your array-creation in each loop iteration (with copying all "now existent" entries) is the source of all evil :-). Try to define one outer list object, which will be filled within the loop withjout replacing this object.

Comment: `np.loadtxt` and `np.genfromtxt`, which load data from a csv file, both collect the data line by line in a list (or rather list of lists), and create the array at the end.  For files where you don't know the length (number of lines) that's the most efficient pure Python method.

Comment: @sascha oops, forgot to remove those three lines with tempArr, those aren't used anymore ^^;  This is the code now that's 20% more efficient.  The last indentation is correct though, the `xyzi_point_array[:,n] =` lines are correctly indented

Comment: Agree with the advice from @hpaulj. Also worth trying to [read the data with Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) which may be faster.